# Communicating between C# and Perl

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am looking for a reliable way of communicating between C# and Perl, I have already tried SOAP::Lite - although I am not to fond of it personally, are there any other methods to accomplish this?

Comment: Communicating for what purpose? What's the bigger picture here?

Comment: Mixing oil and water gives you Majonaise (modulo eggs) - so no yummy tuna sandwiches without it

Comment: Specifically, are you talking about two regular windows apps? two desktop apps?  a desktop and a windows app?  Are either a windows service?  In short, what, exactly are you trying to accomplish?