# SOAP Server using C# and PERL

Tags: c#, .net, windows, perl

I have a functional SOAP server using Perl and a C# client:

SOAP Server (Perl):

```
use SOAP::Lite +trace;
use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;
my $daemon = SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Daemon
  -> new (LocalAddr => '123.123.123.123', LocalPort => 8001, listen => 5);
$daemon -> dispatch_to('Queryserver::queryserver');
print "Contact SOAP server at ", $daemon->url, "\n";
$daemon->handle();
```

C# Client:

```
 public class Client : SoapHttpClientProtocol
    {

        public Client()
        {
            this.Url = "http://123.123.123.123:8001/QUERYSERVER";
        }

        [SoapDocumentMethod("urn:Queryserver#queryserver", RequestNamespace = "urn:Queryserver", ResponseNamespace = "urn:Queryserver", ResponseElementName = "queryserverResponse")]
        [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("result")]
        public virtual string queryserver()
        {
            System.Object[] results = this.Invoke("queryserver", new object[0]);
            return ((string)(results[0].ToString()));
        }
    }

    class QueryServer
    {

        // this public string stores the cpuworld soap function, so the CPUObject can access it.

        public string resultQueryserverLoad;

        public void queryserver()
        {

            //bug fix below
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            // end bugfix

            Client queryserverClient = new Client();

            string result;
            try
            {
                result = queryserverClient.queryserver();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                result = exception.Message;
            }

            resultQueryserverLoad = result;
            //Console.WriteLine(result);
            //Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

In the C# client I invoke the "Queryserver" class and "queryserver" method with the help of SOAP, although I would like to be able to invoke other methods in other classes via the C# client, how could I include an additional "dispatch_to('Queryserver::queryserver');" in the PERL soap server?

E.g.

```
use SOAP::Lite +trace;
use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;
my $daemon = SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Daemon
  -> new (LocalAddr => '123.123.123.123', LocalPort => 8001, listen => 5);
$daemon -> dispatch_to('Queryserver::queryserver');
           **dispatch_to('<other class>::<other method>');**
print "Contact SOAP server at ", $daemon->url, "\n";
$daemon->handle();
```

Comment: Seems you found *a way for communicating between C# and Perl* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900482/communicating-between-c-sharp-and-perl

Comment: @L.B haha :P far from reliable, but it's the best I have found so far, looking at RabbitMQ at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not read the documentation. [`dispatch_to`](http://p3rl.org/SOAP%3a%3aLite#DYNAMIC-DEPLOYMENT-EXAMPLE) takes a list.

```
dispatch_to(
    'Queryserver::queryserver',
    'OtherClass::other_method',
);
```

You probably want to define just one class and have all its public methods available for dispatch instead of enumerating lots of fully-qualified method names manually.